# State Change causing GraphQL runs again in react

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am seeing one scenario in react when using graphQL with it. In the following code, whenever, the code comes to onPaginationChange method, it also, goes to getVariables method and eventually it makes a call to GraphQL to get the data. How does it happen?

Does the change in state in onPaginationChange method causes refresh in all places which are dependent on state? Is it a react thing? Or some graphQL thing? In below code, I have provided the main things that I thing would be useful. I have removed the exact implementation of Table as I don't think it would be required for this question to answer.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";

export const LIST_ITEMS = gql`
  query list(
    $pageIndex: Int
    $limit: Int
  ) {
    listItems(
      limit: $limit
      pageIndex: $pageIndex
    ) {
      items {
        name
        description
      }
      totalCount
    }
  }
`;

export class ManageItems extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentPageIndex: 1,
      pagesCount: 1,
      pageSize: 30
    };
  }

  getVariables() {
    // It comes here whenever there onPaginationChange function is called. HOW?
    return {
      pageIndex: this.state.currentPageIndex - 1,
      limit: this.state.pageSize
    };
  }

  onPaginationChange({ detail }) {
    this.setState({
      currentPageIndex: detail.currentPageIndex,
      pageSize: detail.pageSize
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { t } = this.props;

    return (
      <Query
        query={LIST_ITEMS}
        variables={this.getVariables()}}
      >
        {({ loading, error, data }) => {
          if (error)
            return ("error");

          return (
            <Table onPaginationChange={this.onPaginationChange.bind(this)}>
            </Table>
          );
        }}
      </Query>
    );
  }
}

export ManageItems;
```

Comment: Is there any good docs or video which you will recommend to read or watch? I read little bit things online. Its difficult to understand/remember all these concepts. Sometimes, they are not covered also.

Comment: https://www.robinwieruch.de/learn-react-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are updating a state in React (using the `this.setState()`), the component is re-render. That's why the `this.getVariables()` will be executed. If the variables are differents from what you previously inputted to the query, apollo will fetch your backend.

I suggest you look into `fetchMore` from `react-apollo`, or making your GraphQL Query inside a component which handles only one page.